# yaml/symfony2: Override configurations

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, monolog

I wanto to override some configurations from config_dev.yml in my config_test.yml. So, imagine the following part in the config_dev.yml:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: stream
            path: %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
            level: debug
        firephp:
            type: firephp
            level: info
```

In my test environment, I want no logger at all. So I tried

```
monolog: ~
```

with no effect. I also tried:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main: ~
        firephp: ~
```

again without any effect. Then I tested

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: ~
            path: ~
            level: ~
        firephp:
            type: ~
            level: ~
```

and I get a ErrorException `Couldn't find constant Monolog\Logger::`. If anybody could point out a way to override the monolog settings I would very much appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Wan you post your entier config_test.yml file ?

Comment: you should imprt config_dev.yml in config_test.yml at the top of the file.

Comment: This should be named "Disable monolog". Sure you want to know how to override a configuration but this your actual description specificly asks how to override/disable monolog settings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's better to define handlers as empty array:

```
monolog:
    handlers: []
```

**UPD1:** There are special type of loggers: test and null, you can use them:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        test:
            type:  test
            level: debug
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything. test.log gets written all the time.

Comment: Your UPD1 works fine :) I got rid of the level and changed the type: `type: "none"`. I think this is easier to understand than the type test, but the behaviour is the same!

Comment: Update all your handlers to type "test".

Answer (score 3):

### If you're using the Symfony2 Standard Edition

Your `config_dev.yml` looks something like this for monolog out of the box:

```
# config_dev.yml
monolog:
  handlers:
    main:
      type: fingers_crossed
      action_level: error
      handler: nested
    nested:
      type: stream
      path: %kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log
      level: debug
```

As you can see this defines the handlers `main` and `nested` where `nested` is only used because it's referenced by `main`.

`config_dev.yml` is imported from `config_test.yml` so
if you want to override the configuration for your test environment you need to override the `main`handler in `config_test.yml`:

```
# config_text.yml
monolog:
    handlers:
      main:
        type: test
```

This will stop monolog from creating a log file.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
monolog:
    handlers: ~
```

It should work (I think).
[Look here](https://github.com/symfony/MonologBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/MonologExtension.php)
Without handlers, monolog is not load.

Comment: No luck with that either. test.log gets written as usual.