# Behat testing in Symfony2 displaying unwanted debug info

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.1, behat

When I am running Behat tests in my Symfony2 project I get lots of unwanted debug lines like the following:

```
[2013-02-01 17:07:50] request.INFO: Matched route "homepage" (parameters: "_controller": "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\RedirectController::redirectAction", "route": "Acme_tasks_tasks", "permanent": "true", "_route": "homepage") [] []
[2013-02-01 17:07:51] security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
[2013-02-01 17:07:51] security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
[2013-02-01 17:07:51] security.DEBUG: Username "john" was reloaded from user provider. [] []
[2013-02-01 17:07:51] security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

My `behat.yml` looks like this:

```
default:
  formatter:
    name: progress
  extensions:
    Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
      mink_driver: true
      kernel:
        env: test
        debug: false
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base_url: 'http://local.acme.ch/app_test.php/'
      default_session: symfony2
      javascript_session: selenium
      selenium:
        host: 33.33.33.1
        port: 4444
```

As you can see I already turned off the kernel's debugging mode Where could all this stuff come from?

My installation is based on Behat's Symfony2 Extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13347822/407697) eventually helped me.

I had to disable monolog in my `config_test.yml` like this:

```
#config_test.yml
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type: test
```

This worked after I also cleared the cache for my test environment with `php app/console cache:clear  --env=test`.

Answer (score 0):

Your client is accessing your application via the front controller `app_test.php`, when using mink and selenium.

You need to tweak this `app_test.php` file:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('test', false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already have a `app_test.php` containing this exact line. So this is not the cause of it.